# When does a zero-time MIDI event trigger?

Tags: midi

I'm reading a MIDI file and I'm having trouble determining when next events trigger.

Let's say I have a midi file that has a track like this (where T=n is the delta time):

`[T=0: Note On, C4] [T=128: Note Off, C4] [T=0: Note On, D4] [T=128: Note Off, D4]`

Does the second Note On (D4) take place at the EXACT same time/tick as the previous Note Off (C4)? Or do you trigger it on the next tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the two events happen at the same time.

In practice, events need a certain time to be sent over MIDI (about one millisecond for three bytes), but the second event will be sent as soon as possible after the first one.
When no actual MIDI cable is involved, the events actually could take effect at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

All events happen on a tick.  However, they're sent out over the MIDI cable one at a time since MIDI is both a serial protocol and serial hardware.  This became a problem with devices that sent out huge numbers of controller change messages, originally like the MIDI guitar controllers.  They simply sent out more MIDI messages per second than the cable could transmit.

On alternate transport, like USB, those events can happen closer together but because they are serial, they must still happen one after the other.  That time frame may be indistiguishable, (we hope), but there will always be a tiny lag.

For them to happen at the "same" time, you must either a) buffer or b) make them happen in different places, as with parallel players, which still leaves you with a delay in syncing.